# At what point can I call GPL code my code?

Tags: legal

I need some legal advice if possible.

So I'm going to be implementing some code under OSS license. I realize that even if I rewrote the implementation, I need to include the license.

However a lot of sources that I use to learn are under GPL Licenses. So even if I take what I learned and implemented it in my own way and heavily modified the code, with the only similarities being logic flow, I still can't claim the work as my own?

What about algorithms that are extremely proficient? (Like binary Heaps)
Do I need to include the inventor of the binary heap into my code?

Also, as I understand it from GPL, if I use the code, even modified, does this mean I need to release the all of my code that even associates with it? So if I make a whole application in a closed system and I plan to sell it, I still have to release all my code via OSS license?

Let me know if I need to provide more information about my question, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "when do you have *some* copyright on the code," or "when do you have *exclusive* copyright on the code?" The first gives you standing to enforce the license on the code; the second means your code contains nothing owned by anyone else, so you don't need to worry about the license of your inspiration. The first attaches very early; the second is extremely fact-dependent and is ultimately up to a court, though there are common approaches.

Comment: @cpast Thanks for the comment. I guess I would mean exclusive copyright. Because the code is very general. It is implemented in a broad way as if there isn't any other way to effectively achieve the same objective. It's as if I'm reading a tutorial, but the at the end it says to be sure to mention the tutorial writer at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license on a given piece of software is only relevant if you are using *that particular piece of software* (or a part of it, or a version of it you've modified yourself, or a part of it that you've modified, etc). If you write an equivalent piece of software yourself, completely 100% from scratch, then there is no license on it until you choose one yourself.

What you appear to be worried about are **software patents**, not licenses. The GPL doesn't let you sue someone for writing code that uses a similar algorithm or UI elements (assuming you didn't actually use any GPL'd code in your re-implementation), but patents do. And a lot of real software companies have ludicrously broad patents that may or may not hold up in court, if only to act as a defense when other companies try to sue them with their own patents.

If you need actual legal advice on how big of a risk this is for your project, you definitely need to consult a lawyer. Patents are hard. If you're just curious, then you may find it interesting to read about some high-profile "clean room reimplementations" such as Google's Dalvik VM for Java, [which Oracle attempted to sue for patent infringement but lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.). I would also *guess* that the people/companies who publish GPL'd code in the first place are probably not the kind of people/companies who sue others over software patents, but of course there's no guarantee.

Comment: This is a good answer, Ixrec. Did you consider to commit to the proposal for the new Stackexchange site [Open Source Stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234/open-source?referrer=LYVOhcyWjB2btmuqLjy44w2)? It still needs 78 people to commit to it so it can go into beta.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks. I have very little practical experience with these issues so it's rare I can give an answer like this on a licensing Q, but once I finish my Mythology.SE commitment I'll consider it.

Comment: @Ixrec Thanks for the answer. I fear that my implementation of the code would be too similar. For example, a lot of it has to deal with math calculations and get/set data. Also uses API calls for registering and unregistering objects. Perhaps there is another way I can implement it, but it would be relatively the same procedure.

Comment: @Stealthguy Copying the API and using known mathematical facts is *probably* fine (at least, no sane person would consider it an infringement), but if you're planning on selling this and still don't feel safe you might want to talk to a lawyer next.

Comment: @Ixrec Well Right, well let me be more specific I guess. I'm using UE4, and I'm building a voxel system. The source code I'm looking at helps tackle how to set up a global voxel grid system that helps keep the cubes together and such. So a lot of the code is looking up a particular voxel and making changes. I feel like my implementation of how to set up the voxel grid and doing get/set data for it would be too similar. But this is coming from limited experience. I may yet figure out an implementation that's original once I learn more.

Comment: Okay, I feel comfortable with this after some more research on my end. I even contacted the developer and they helped clarify a few of my issues. Will accept as answer.